# Jquery .load img not working in firefox and IE!

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript in my website and its works great to load image on click but not fork in Firefox or IE!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                  $("#photo1").click(function(){
                    var img = new Image();
                    $(img).load(function () {
                        $('#big-image').hide();
                        $('#big-image').attr('src', '{/literal}{$purl}/t/{$p.p1}?{$smarty.now}{literal}');  
                        $('#big-image').fadeIn();
                    }).error(function() {
                    }).attr('src', '{/literal}{$purl}/t/{$p.p1}?{$smarty.now}{literal}');
                  });
                  {/literal}
                  {if $p.p2 ne ""}
                  {literal}
                  $("#photo2").click(function(){
                    var img = new Image();
                    $(img).load(function () {
                        $('#big-image').hide();
                        $('#big-image').attr('src', '{/literal}{$purl}/t/{$p.p2}?{$smarty.now}{literal}');  
                        $('#big-image').fadeIn();
                    }).error(function() {
                    }).attr('src', '{/literal}{$purl}/t/{$p.p2}?{$smarty.now}{literal}');
                  });
                  {/literal}
                  {/if}
                  {if $p.p2 ne ""}
                  {literal}
                  $("#photo3").click(function(){
                    var img = new Image();
                    $(img).load(function () {
                        $('#big-image').hide();
                        $('#big-image').attr('src', '{/literal}{$purl}/t/{$p.p3}?{$smarty.now}{literal}');  
                        $('#big-image').fadeIn();
                    }).error(function() {
                    }).attr('src', '{/literal}{$purl}/t/{$p.p3}?{$smarty.now}{literal}');
                  });
                  {/literal}
                  {/if}
                  {literal}
                });
                $(document).ready( function() {
                 $('.gig-desc').linkify();
                    $(".gig-desc a").each(function() {
                        $(this).attr("target", "_blank");
                    });
                });
                </script>
```

And here is image div tag:

```
<div id="photo1"><img alt="{$p.gtitle|stripslashes}" src="{$purl}/t2/{$p.p1}?{$smarty.now}" /></div>    
{if $p.p2 ne ""}<div id="photo2"><img alt="{$p.gtitle|stripslashes}" src="{$purl}/t2/{$p.p2}?{$smarty.now}" /></div>{/if}
{if $p.p3 ne ""}<div id="photo3"><img alt="{$p.gtitle|stripslashes}" src="{$purl}/t2/{$p.p3}?{$smarty.now}" /></div>{/if}
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you checked the error console of FireFox. Maybe there is/was a helpful error message?

Comment: please show the code that is in your browser, not the code form your smarty template

Answer (score 1):

There are peaces of code in your javascript that (I think) are not javascript, Smarty tags perhaps? Tthe firebug console launches an error there.

```
{/literal}
{if $p.p2 ne ""}
{literal}
```